# for cycle for hashtable C#

Tags: c#, hashtable

I can use 'foreach' for iteration Hashtable, but i need in use cycle with index (for)

I use this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var field in Hashtable) {
    i++;
    //action
}
```

but i think this is not good

**I NEED CYCLE 'FOR'**

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: I can use 'foreach' for iteration Hashtable, but i need in use cycle with index (for)

Answer (score 2):

For loops are useful for collections that can be indexes by numbers.
Therefore the only useful way to iterate over a HashTable is to iterate over the Hashtables keys.

```
var keys = hashtable.Keys.ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
   var value = hashtable[keys[i]];
```

Comment: sorry, but this dont compile. Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type '...Collections'

Answer (score 0):

When `i` is even, do something, and when `i` is odd do something else.

Comment: Did the question originally say anything about odd and even numbers?

Comment: @Rawling No, but it's a cycle.